# I want to make a bank-connected Twitter bot

Tags: twitter, bots, bank

I was wondering if it were possible to link my brokerage to a Twitter bot. I want to create one that automatically tweets trades I place. I am a beginner and don't know where to start. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first place I would start is checking if whatever brokerage you use exposes some kind of API or data feed for you to be able to programatically access your trade data. Without that, beginning the project will already be rather difficult unless you plan to manually fill in the trade information somewhere.